# Docker pulling - authorization required

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While trying to play around with [container](https://github.com/Marcel-Jan/docker-hadoop-spark),

Some time into the `docker-compose up` I get:

```
...
 - presto-coordinator Pulling                                                                                                                                                        507.2s
   - 6d827a3ef358 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 2726297beaf1 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 7d27bd3d7fec Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - e61641c845ed Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - cce4cca5b76b Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 6826227500b0 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - c03b117ffd91 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 821a1547b435 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 53d8cd7022f9 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - adeb8ae151f4 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 48d9dad952fc Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - f55b5ba1a0f9 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - dfe31f13fb6a Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 30a71e496ee1 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 7fa335f1d6a7 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 8f8cf691c243 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 017d225c721b Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - df1d318013a5 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - cba65d108f7e Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
   - 1608bd18a946 Waiting                                                                                                                                                            506.2s
 - hive-metastore Pulling                                                                                                                                                            507.2s
   - f49cf87b52c1 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                      234.0s
   - 1778b563ad5e Pull complete                                                                                                                                                      234.1s
   - 46210e4b5de7 Download complete                                                                                                                                                  506.2s
   - f77335d29f88 Download complete                                                                                                                                                  506.2s
   - 11669b117fd9 Download complete                                                                                                                                                  506.2s
   - 790d93d9ab2a Download complete                                                                                                                                                  506.2s
   - 60c95a1f3ed5 Download complete                                                                                                                                                  506.2s
   - 16e2394e4df8 Downloading [===========>                                       ]  54.13MB/244.3MB                                                                                 506.2s
   - 8e3699eb8fe9 Downloading                                                                                                                                                        506.2s
unauthorized: authentication required
PS C:\Users\synct\docker-hadoop-spark>
```

Here is my `config.json` file

```
PS C:\Users\synct> more .\.docker\config.json
{"credsStore":"desktop"}

PS C:\Users\synct>
```

What's the fix?

Comment: Can you please post your `config.json` file?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: Best guess is a proxy on the network is doing something to the connection.

Comment: Please be careful posting the users `~/.docker/config.json`, since it may contain credentials to servers that you do not want to publicly expose. Fortunately in this case, it only included a pointer to the external cred store.

Comment: The `16e...` blob appears to be around 244M where many of the other layers are rather small, so it could be something choking on the file size. Again, I'd look to something like a proxy on the network doing something to the request.